# eclipse search in history

Tags: eclipse, version-control

It is possible to search in previous revisions of saved file? 
This is internal eclipse version system which is accessible on History view, not svn or anything like it.

Comment: Not, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: **[Local history](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm)**?

Comment: @misha I'm afraid not, but I recommend the **[EGit](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egit-git-team-provider)** for local version control / alternative for **Local History** of Eclipse.

Comment: @michaelnesterenko did you ever find out how to do it?  And, maybe you want to edit the question to make it clear that you want to search through all files in history at once, not manually, one by one

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Project on the folder "(insert workspace root here)\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.history" and do a file search on this project.

Don't forget to add a plain "*" to the "File name patterns" in the Search window, as the Eclipse history files have no file extension at all (so they would not be found by "*.*").

Comment: This is a veruy clumsly way of doing it it. Is there no way to search the history without creating a dummy project?

Answer (score 0):

right click the project in eclipse..then click history and maximize history by double clicking on it.. then check for a button's icon like multiple arrows click it and search with comments or author.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the **Eclipse local history** on your file system using unix commands.

- The Eclipse local history is stored in `eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history`
- Files are randomly named (./53/c05661ce5d3d001a1f3eef73aaebdbfd), so you'll need to search for content.
- The `grep` command below lists all files containing "WHATEVER", i.e. your latest changes.
- The `find` command below does the same plus it shows the last updated timestamp, so you can pick out the file with the latest changes.

```
$ cd eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history
$ grep -r "WHATEVER"
- OR
$ find . -exec grep "WHATEVER" '{}' \; -ls 2>/dev/null
```